# CC1352P launchpad SPI Interface is not working for my appliation

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, spi, texas-instruments

Working on Simplelink MCU CC1352P/ any CC13xx Launchpad interfacing E-paper display via SPI TI-RTOS. The code has no error and no warnings in CCS IDE. but SPI TX is not happening. SPI mode Master. Here is my code please have a look on my code let me know what is the problem.

**SPI Configuration and transferring code**

```
SPI_Params_init(&spiParams);
spiParams.frameFormat = SPI_POL0_PHA0;
spiParams.bitRate = 10000000;
spiParams.mode = SPI_MASTER;
spiParams.dataSize = 8;
masterSpi = SPI_open(EPD_SPI0, &spiParams);
if (masterSpi == NULL) {
   printf("Error initializing master SPI\n");
   while (1);
}
else {
   printf("Master SPI Opened\n");
}
sleep(3);

GPIO_write(EPD_CS,0);
GPIO_write(EPD_DC,0);
transaction.count = 10;
transaction.txBuf = (void *) com;
transaction.rxBuf = NULL;
transferOK = SPI_transfer(masterSpi, &transaction);
if (!transferOK){
  printf("Error Transfer\n");
}
else{
  printf("SPI Transferred\n");
}
DELAY_S(6);
```

[Figure1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1j7JF.jpg)[Figure2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfLtK.jpg)[Figure3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2x0V.jpg)

Comment: @LPs please let me know what have you edited and also suggest to me if you have any opinion on this.

Comment: I removed a tag and added [tag_embedded]. It could help you finding people that can help you.

Comment: @LPs Thank you so much. Do you have any idea on this ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with MCU CC1352P..

Comment: @LPs are you familiar with any other simplelink MCU's.

Comment: What did ti say when you asked them?

Comment: What is your basis for believing that this is correct and complete SPI initialization, including that you do not need to do anything else to get the pins to function in that mode?  Which if any of your debug messages are output? What do you see on the SPI lines with a scope or logic analyzer?   What happens if you try some other known-good SPI example for this MCU?  Even if you don't have the peripheral chip an example is supposed to talk to, you should still see some bus activity.   Remove the delays and put your code in a loop so it keeps trying.

Comment: @ChrisStratton  I have done as per the TI SDK SPI example. Debugging messages works correctly by monitoring all the statuses. I cannot see any thing in Scope if use 3 wire mode.
And if I use 4 wire mode I can able to see this CLK signal in scope Figure3. In mosi if I send 0x11,0x22 I getting this response Figure1. 
 
if I send data as 0x01, 0x02 I gt this response in scope Figure2. Figures added in question please have a look